# Why isn't it giving me the empty set?

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop, reverse

I have the following code:

```
a=[[2,3],[3,2]]
new=[i for i in a if i.reverse not in a]
print(new)
```

This gives me:

```
[[2,3],[3,2]]
```

But it should give me the empty set since the reverse of [2,3] is [3,2] which is an element of the set a.

What should I be fixing?

Comment: `i.reverse` is a method.  What's more, that method returns `None`.  You're likely looking for `[i for i in a if i[::-1] not in a]`

Comment: Thank you Patrick, that sure was it. You have saved my life.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Put that as an answer my good sir

Answer (score 1):

You should be careful about the built-in `reverse()` attribute, as it reverses in-place. Depending on your use case, it might be better to use the built-in operator `reversed()`.

```
>> a = [[2, 3], [3, 2]]
>> new = [i for i in a if reversed(i) not in a]
>> print(new)
[[2, 3], [3, 2]]
```

That doesn't work! It's due to the fact that `reversed()` will return an iterator object, and that evaluates to `False` if checked against `a`:

```
>> reversed([2, 3])
<list_reverseiterator at 0x1c1d9cd550>

>> reversed([2, 3]) in a
False
```

Hence, you need to use `list()` to evaluate the iterator:

```
>> a = [[2, 3], [3, 2]]
>> new = [i for i in a if list(reversed(i)) not in a]
>> print(new)
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in you code.

First you are not calling the method `list.reverse`, but merely checking if it is in the `list`.

```
if i.reverse not in a
```

Second, `list.reverse` reverses the `list`, it does not return a new one.

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> output = l.reverse()
>>> print(output)
None
>>> l
[3, 2, 1]
```

This means even calling the method would be incorrect as it would return the wrong result *and* mutate your list `a`.

### Solution

Note that using `in` against a `list` needs to traverse the entire list. Thus, for big data sets, it is better to use a `set` for constant-time lookup.

```
a = [[2, 3], [3, 2]]
set_for_lookup = set(map(tuple, a))

new = [i for i in a if tuple(i) not in set_for_lookup]

print(new) # []
```

The overhead of building a `set` will make this slightly slower for small lists, but will significantly improve your algorithm for large data, passing from *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* to *O(n)*.